# Use RegEx to match data in cell in order to pull out to new rows in Excel

Tags: regex, excel

I have a spreadsheet containing numerous cells of data, but each cell contains numerous lines without carriage return or line feed.  I want to create new rows by matching each occurrence of a ten digit number and grabbing the number and all text up until the next occurrence.

For example, this is one cell's text.

```
8770304350 PRINTER 4610-2CR W/IRON GRAY COVERS (2921)    $750.75  2881057001 PAYMENT DEVICE - VERIFONE MX915 - WALMART CONSIGNE  8770242020 DISPLAY 4820-5GB USB W/ I/O SUPPORT IRON GRAY   $907.27  8770242216 KEYPAD-MSR 3 TRACK IRON GREY    $213.85  2881037020 CONSIGNED- SCANNER DS6878-SR20117WR IMAGER 2D BLUE
```

I want to split it into new rows each time there is a ten digit number so it would end up looking like this where each line is a new row.

```
8770304350 PRINTER 4610-2CR W/IRON GRAY COVERS (2921)    $750.75  
2881057001 PAYMENT DEVICE - VERIFONE MX915 - WALMART CONSIGNE  
8770242020 DISPLAY 4820-5GB USB W/ I/O SUPPORT IRON GRAY   $907.27  
8770242216 KEYPAD-MSR 3 TRACK IRON GREY    $213.85  
2881037020 CONSIGNED- SCANNER DS6878-SR20117WR IMAGER 2D BLUE
```

I tried using RegEx on my own, but i was either matching just the number or the entire string and it's very complicated to me.

For example, this tried the look ahead but ended up selecting all text except first number and last selection.

```
(?<=[0-9]{10}).*(?=[0-9]{10})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\b\d{10}.*?(?=\s*\b\d{10}|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JIfbk9/2). If there can be line breaks, replace `.*?` with `[\s\S]*?`.

**Details**

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `\d{10}` - 10 digits
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=\s*\b\d{10}|$)` - a positive lookahead that, immediately to the right of the current location, requires

  - `\s*\b\d{10}` - 0+ whitespaces, word boundary and 10 digits
  - `|` - or
  - `$` - end of string.

Comment: you nailed it, works perfectly.  thanks for the quick response.